# Show IE "Save As" dialog using Watin

Tags: c#, watin, savefiledialog

Has anybody has done this? Navigating to a web page and pop up the save as dialog? In this way, the browser can handle the file type, html, pdf, etc...

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to this to be when a FileHandler is called or on a static webpage?

If it is on a Handler page where the content type is returned then according the latest WatiN release documentation then you can do as follows:

```
using(IE ie = new IE(someUrlToGoTo))
{
    FileDownloadHandler fileDownloadHandler = new FileDownloadHandler(fullFileName);
    ie.AddDialogHandler(fileDownloadHandler);

    ie.Link("startDownloadLinkId").Click();

    fileDownloadHandler.WaitUntilFileDownloadDialogIsHandled(15);
    fileDownloadHandler.WaitUntilDownloadCompleted(200);
}
```

Paul

Comment: Thanks Paul but what i mean is that my application will force IE to show the Save As Dialog. The PDF is opened already in IE and I just want to save it.

Comment: Paul do you know how to do a file overwrite?

Comment: @Gabriel Guimarães - when you say file overwrite what do you mean?

Comment: I mean that the file I'm saving on disk already exists, and I need to overwrite it.

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.DeleteSubKeyTree(".pdf");

run this Registry.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question.