# Save current webpage in Watin

Tags: save, watin

I'm trying to save the full content of the current static web page, using the code from [Show IE "Save As" dialog using Watin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546047/show-save-as-dialog-of-ie-using-watin)

So here it is:

IE ie = new IE("http://localhost");
// more code

//I expect out.html is the output file
            FileDownloadHandler fileDownloadHandler = new FileDownloadHandler("out.html");

//I expect this line to popup the save as dialog box, but nothing happens
            ie.AddDialogHandler(fileDownloadHandler);

//the program is blocked at this line, as it can't click anywhere
            ie.Link("startDownloadLinkId").Click();

```
        fileDownloadHandler.WaitUntilFileDownloadDialogIsHandled(15); 
        fileDownloadHandler.WaitUntilDownloadCompleted(200);
```

I also tried the code below, but it doesn't save all the page:
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("output.html");
file.Write(ie.Html);

Again, I need to save the webpage from Watin, and the result to be the same as saving it manually.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I do it:

```
File.WriteAllText("myfile.html", 
(myIE.InternetExplorer as SHDocVw.InternetExplorer).Document.documentElement.outerHtml);
```

Assumes myIE is a WatiN IE element, of course.

If you're ever having difficulty finding how to do something with WatiN, I often find it helpful to google how to do it with an *"Internet Explorer COM object"*. WatiN wraps the object, but it is exposed and able to be accessed!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try to parse the html with html agility pack and save it, there are additional abilities that you can use...

```
        using HtmlAgilityPack;

        var htmldoc = new HtmlDocument();
        htmldoc.LoadHtml(ie.Html);
        htmldoc.Save(stream);
```

[Link to agility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I tried HtmlAgilityPack, but it doesn't work, as it produces the same output as: file.Write(ie.Html). I need to get the same output as from viewing the source code in the browser itself.

Comment: Since ie.Html only returns the *downloaded* html, no changes made by javascript will be visible in your saved html file.